# Search in vim for string starting and ending with a pattern

Tags: vim

Let's say I want to highlight/search all the lines in a file opened with `vim` with following criteria.

Criteria: Lines which start with `"start123"` and end with `"321end"`. There could be anything between these two patterns.

I tried following but no luck.

`/^start123\&321end$`

Ofcourse I can do this on bash with `grep -G '^start123' teest|grep -G '321end$'` But I want to highlight this strings in vim. Just wondering.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just match *anything* (`.*`) between the start and end patterns:

```
/^start123.*321end$
```

Comment: Perfect. I was close it means..

Comment: Close only counts in horseshoes and hand grenades. ;-)